# Integrate WebSocket with Pipedream

Tags: node.js, websocket, pushbullet, pipedream

I have a platform that uses real-time data stream using a web socket; I wonder how I can implement this web socket into Pipedream so that whenever the web socket receives a new notification, Pipedream will manipulate that notification as per the workflow.

Platform is: https://www.pushbullet.com

```
Code Sample: https://jsfiddle.net/pushbullet/u92DA/
```

Documentation: https://docs.pushbullet.com/#realtime-event-stream

Is that possible using Node JS for example?